# Don't push if the 'debugger' in code by git

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks

I'm using git and Bitbucket and I don't want push if any `debugger` word in codes. Is it possible? How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of git hooks. 
For more information see: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks.

I think, you can either use pre-commit or pre-push depending on how you want to restrict yourself.

Comment: Feel free to come back here, if you want any help in writing the git hooks. But please do the research first :)